# Horizontal alignment using multicols and parts (exam package)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicol, exam

I'm having trouble with horizontal alignment using **multicols** and **exercises** parts in the exam package. The items that I'm writing are not aligning horizontally as show the minimal example bellow

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is a question with parts bellow

        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \begin{parts}
                \part $A^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

                \part $\det A = 1$

                \part $X = \begin{pmatrix} -9 \\ -8 \\ -7 \\ -6 \end{pmatrix}$
            \end{parts}
        \end{multicols}

    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I fix the horizontal alignment using the exam package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need `multicols`, and I think you mean *the items that I'm writing are not aligning **vertically***. Instead of `multicols`, you can use `parbox`s which are vertically centered by default.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \question This is a question with parts bellow
    \begin{parts}
        \parbox{.3\linewidth}{%
        \part $A^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
        }\hfill
        \parbox{.3\linewidth}{%
        \part $\det A = 1$
        }\hfill
        \parbox{.3\linewidth}{%
        \part $X = \begin{pmatrix} -9 \\ -8 \\ -7 \\ -6 \end{pmatrix}$
        }
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! That was what I'm lookgin for!

Answer (score 0):

Modify the 2nd part to become:

```
\part $\det A = 1 \vphantom{\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}}$
```

(Those 1s aren't really necessary.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Also works that way.